# Change image source using jquery after replacing the original file

Tags: php, jquery, image

I came across a very peculiar problem lately...

I've got the following HTML and javascript

```
<img id="mycoverpicture" src="users/<?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>/cover/cover.jpg" alt="">
```

I'm using dropzone to upload a JPEG image

```
$(".cover-picture").dropzone({
  acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg",
      url: 'includes/coveruploader.php',
      maxFiles: 1,
      maxfilesexceeded: function(file) {
      this.removeAllFiles();
      this.addFile(file);
},
success: function(file, response){   
      $('#mycoverpicture').attr('src','users/'+sessionuser+'/cover/cover.jpg');
        }
});
```

As you can see, as the dropzone finishes uploading the cover picture, the image source changes. But the problem here is I have the following scenario.

Directory:

```
users/username/cover/cover.jpeg
```

When a user uploads a cover picture the cover.jpg is replaced there. So when the source of the image is changed dynamically, the old image still exists.

Is it because of the cache?

Should I clear the cache memory via PHP or JavaScript?

If I clear the cache memory, there is a problem again. When the user reloads the page or navigates to another page, all images and fonts would be downloaded again. Performance issue will exist...

I need a neat way to achieve the image change with same file name.

Comment: just try: `$('#mycoverpicture').attr('src','users/'+sessionuser+'/cover/cover.jpg?'+ $.now());` this will avoid caching issue

Comment: @A.Wolff I posted that same answer before noticing your comment. I'll delete mine if you wish.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Keep your answer, i was just too lazy to post comment as answer... ;)

Answer (score 2):

How about replace the existing image with a new one? That should remove the cache problem.

```
success: function (file, response) {
     $("#mycoverpicture").replaceWith($("<img/>", {
        src: 'users/' + sessionuser + '/cover/cover.jpg',
        id: mycoverpicture
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try appending some random garbage to the image path, prefixed with a question mark. When you want to force the image to refresh, change the random garbage.

```
var filename = 'cover.jpg?r=' + Math.random().toString();
$('#mycoverpicture').attr('src','users/'+sessionuser+'/cover/'+filename);
```

This will defeat caching. The browser has no idea what the server is doing with that "query string" and will have to assume that it might be getting a new image, so it'll discard what's in cache. The server knows better and will simply ignore it the query string, and serve what it's currently got in that file -- the new image.